# how to use apex:inputField type of time

Tags: datetime, inputfield, time

According to the docs on `apex:inputField`:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputField.htm

I can use `type="time"`. However when I try this with a date-time field I get the compliation error:

> Expected input type 'datetime-local', got 'time' for Datetime data
>   type

What type of field could I use this with then if not date-time? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

There is a [Time Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_time.htm) in Apex that you can use. See my example below for how to get the current time displayed in the HTML 5 time input field

**Controller:**

```
public class MyTimeController {

    public Time myTime { 
        get {
            if (myTime == null) {
                myTime =  DateTime.now().time();
            }
            return myTime;
        } 
        set;
    }
}
```

**VisualForce Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="MyTimeController" docType="html-5.0"> 
   <apex:form>
      Enter Time: <apex:input type="time" value="{!myTime}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**NB:** HTML5 `input` tags may not be supported on all browsers. It would be advisable to check a service such as [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) to make sure that your target browser supports it.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I was probably just going to go with a regular HTML input type of time. However, my question is why is type="time" listed as an option on apex:inputField ? Is there any scenario where that can actually be used?

Comment: One scenario I can think of would be to have a Date input field and a Time input field. The results of which could be combined to produce a DateTime. I never liked SF's field for entering DateTime, its not intuitive to know how to change the time.

Comment: Hm, not quite following, so 2 apex:input fields? How is that using an apex:inputfield?